# @TestPropertySource annotation alternative on a method level

Tags: java, spring, testing, annotations, spring-test

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class Aclass {}
```

Is there an alternative that uses properties for the tested instance in a method.

```
@Test
public void aMethod(){}
```

Answer (score 14):

It is still not possible, but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18951) for this feature if you wish to follow it.

Comment: With JUnit 5 you can use `@Nested` test classes, as mentionned in the following reply to the issue : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18951#issuecomment-1153547515. So at least your tests can be contained logically in a single test class.