Registering a Bean with multiple different properties to test ConditionalOnProperties
I have a problem in writing a test for verifying that @ConditionalOnProperty is working correctly. I could not find a solution for registering a bean with multiple application properties to find out whether it is creating a bean or not.
The class that should be created as a bean
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperties(prefix = "card.services.connection", value = "baseUrl")
public CardService {

}

I have tried to implement a test through setting a properties via System.setProperty(..);
@SpringBootTest(classes = CardConfiguration.class)
class ContextTest {

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;


  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("card.services.connection.baseUrl", "http://localhost:8080");
  }

  @Test
  void registerCardBean() {
    context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("cardbean", mock(CardService.class));
    boolean tietob2crest = context.containsBeanDefinition("cardbean");
    Assertions.assertTrue(tietob2crest);
  }

}

In this scenario I got failed test. I do not know why, because I set a property, and indicated in annotation that if there is a existing property then it can create a bean, however it is not working.
Can you suggest, please, one of your best practices for such case.

It seems you are not familiar with testing in Spring boot. You should peruse a tutorial first https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

But the idea is that when the application context starts up, it performs the init by reading application.properties files, JVM system properties etc into the Spring Environment, then once the application ready event is published, the tests can be started. @BeforeEach only occurs IMMEDIATELY before a test, which is well after the Spring Environment has been init. It will not read the property you set in setUp()

The way you should set properties for a test is to use the Spring Annotation @TestPropertySource
You can either pass it a .properties file that contains the test properties, or declare your properties inline. i.e.
@TestPropertySource(properties={"card.services.connection.baseUrl=http://localhost:8080"})

An alternative (assuming you are using Spring Profiles) would be to setup application-test.properties with your test properties, and then annotate your @SpringBootTest class with the @ActiveProfiles annotation like the following so it can read the properties from application-test.properties
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")

Edit:
Based on comment from OP, ApplicationContextRunner is a valid solution as well. See also tutorial from Baeldung showing how to test property condition with ApplicationContextRunner

I guess I could not express my problem clearly. I want to write several test cases in registering the bean but with different properties. Can I do that?

Well, this seems to do what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845576/testpropertysource-annotation-alternative-on-a-method-level. But I would suggest to write separate SpringBootTest that contains each @Test rather than one class with multiple test because it looks like the reloading of the property will dirty the context, though you can annotate each @Test method with @DirtiesContext to reload the application context for each test if you dont want to separate each test

ok, thank you, I will try

I found another solution for this, ApplicationContextRunner. I can pass there the properties and create a bean. Also thank you for your responses, helped me as well.
